# Como saber qual é o último elemento em uma lista?

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Estou fazendo uma query sql dinâmica, no qual utilizo listas, o meu problema é, como saber qual o último elemento desta lista

Segue o código feito até o momento:

```
List<string> campos = new List<string>();

campos.Add("id");
campos.Add("descricao");
campos.Add("Titulo");

string sql = "INSERT INTO teste( ";

foreach (string campo in campos)
{
   sql += campo + ", ";//preciso saber o ultimo elemento para fechar o parênteses ao invés da vírgula
}
```

Comment: pega seu código mesmo e no final retire dois caracteres da string sql... `sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> campos = new List<string>();
campos.Add("id");
campos.Add("descricao");
campos.Add("Titulo");
string sql = "INSERT INTO teste( ";
foreach (string campo in campos)
   sql += campo + ", ";

sql = sql.Substring(0, sql.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 11):

Não necessita de saber qual é o último item da lista.
Após o `foreach` pega na string e faça isto:

```
//Remove a virgula e adiciona o parêntesis
sql = sql.TrimEnd(',') + ")";
```

[String.TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) para fazer isso.

```
List<string> campos = new List<string>();

campos.Add("id");
campos.Add("descricao");
campos.Add("Titulo");

string sql = "INSERT INTO teste(" + string.Join(",", campos) + ")";
```

Verifique o exemplo no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G6uNbz)

Answer (score 4):

Mais uma forma:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO teste( " + campos[0];
for (var i = 1; i < campos.Count; i++) {
    sql +=  ", " + campos[i];
}
```

ou a solução que eu não gosto por usar *flag* mas usa `foreach`:

```
var primeiro = true;
foreach (var campo in campos) {
    sql += (primeiro ? ", " : "") + campo;
    primeiro = false;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RemoveLastComma.cs).

Tem várias outras formas.

Tem chance deste código ter algum problema de SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que usando o for no lugar do foreach seria mais fácil

> Não conheco bastante da linguagem então não sei se é  campos.size() ou campos.length() ou campos.Count

```
List<string> campos = new List<string>();

campos.Add("id");
campos.Add("descricao");
campos.Add("Titulo");

string sql = "INSERT INTO teste( ";
int quantidade = campos.Count;
for(int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
{
   string campo = campos[i];
   if((quantidade  - 1) == i) {
       sql += campo + ") ";// é o ultimo
   } else {
       sql += campo + ", ";// Não é o ultimo
   }
}
```

Comment: A princípio utilizei desta forma, mas ainda usando o foreach.

Comment: isso, da para fazer de várias maneiras. poderia criar uma variável antes do foreach e ir incrementando ela

Answer (score 1):

```
...
string ultimoItem = "";

//verificando se há itens na lista para evitar possíveis erros
if (campos.Count > 0) {
    ultimoItem = campos[campos.Count - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var pos = campos[campos.Count - 1]; //último elelmento da lista

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre faço desse jeito. Só funciona se sua coleção for indexável (`ILIST`)

Inclua `using System.Linq;`

```
List<string> campos = new List<string>();

campos.Add("id");
campos.Add("descricao");
campos.Add("Titulo");

string sql = "INSERT INTO teste( ";

for (int i = 0; i< campos.length -1; i++)
{
   var campo = campos[i]
   sql += campo + ", ";
}

sql += campos.Last() + ");
```